# Unable to get all values of One column in Tbl1(MICROSOFT SQLSERVER JOIN ISSUE)

Tags: sql-server, left-join

Hi I have two tables with me

1. tblSubCategory
2. tblProductSbcategoryVal

I am attaching Image ...
[image]

***What i want to get*** is Name of all the tblSubcategory(SubName)..

***what i have tried so far is following join and output is below***

You can see here There is no tblsubcategory reflecting(Pk_Id=23 , Subname= blaa)...

Any way to get the Subname Blaa . I mean all the SubName of tblsubCategory(left table)

[image]

Comment: Try putting condition in WHERE clause in the ON clause? In short, replace WHERE with AND in the query you have written.

Comment: Solved @DeepanshuKalra ... Thnaks man , you save me

Answer (score 0):

All the non-matching columns of your right table will have NULL value, So they will be eliminated by your SV.ProdId = '1' filter . If you want them to get included you can put one more filter like below :

SELECT pk_Sub
    ,SubName
    ,SV.SubCatValue
FROM tblSubCategory tblProductSbcategoryVal SV ON tblSubCategory.pk_SubId = SV.SubCatId
WHERE SV.ProdId = '1'
    OR SV.SubCatId IS NULL